# p-sylow-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to show that given a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, $|N|=p^k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$, that $N\subseteq P$ where $P$ is a $p$-sylow-subgroup of $G$, for all $P$ $p$-sylow-subgroups. What I have done is the following. Assume that $k$ is the highest power of $p$ for which $p^k|m$ where $m=|G|$. Then $N$ is itself a $p$-sylow-subgroup. Assume there is another $p$-sylow-subgroup, call this $P$. Then the 2nd theorem of Sylow states that there is a $g\in G$ such that $gNg^{-1}=P$, so $gN=Pg=Ng$ because $N$ is a normal subgroup, thus $P=G$. I cant solve the other case, that $k$ is not the highest power such that $p^k|m$, so I am asking for hints. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: All $p$-Sylow subgroups are conjugate, which you already used! And just think about what the means about what subgroups a normal subgroup is inside of.

Comment: You'll need to know that a p-subgroup is contained in a Sylow p-subgroup. Depending on your setup, that is either the definition of a Sylow p-subgroup or one of the Sylow theorems.

Comment: @JackSchmidt what do you mean by "You'll need to know that a p-subgroup is contained in a Sylow p-subgroup"? what is p-subgroup? the definition I use for p-sylow-subgroup is that if $n$ is the highest power such that $p^n$ divides the order of $G$ then a subgroup of order $p^n$ is called a p-sylow-subgroup.

Comment: @KCd if $N$ is in a $p$-sylow-subgroup,then I can easily show that it has to be in all $p$-sylow-subgroups. so how can I show that $N$ is in a $p$-sylow-subgroup?

Comment: @Badshah: a p-subgroup is a subgroup whose order is a power of p (any power of p, not just the highest). You'll need Sylow's containment theorem since it is not part of your definition of Sylow subgroup.

Comment: Badshah: Think about the Sylow theorems for $G/N$.